# Replacement in python package in Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, pip, graphql

GraphQL is still not supported in Django 4, so to use it I need to change the line:

**"from django.utils.encoding import force_text"**

to

**"from django.utils.encoding import force_str as force_text"**

in package

**"VENV/lib/PYTHON_VERSION/site-packages/graphene_django/utils/utils.py"**

The problem occurs when using Docker, how could I replace this line when building the container?

Answer (score 0):

Simply combine [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) with a [`sed`](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-string-in-files/)-replace in your dockerfile.

```
RUN pyver="python$(python --version | grep -Eo '[0-9]\.[0-9]')" && \
    sed -i "s/import force\_text/import force\_str as force\_text/g" \
    ./lib/$pyver/site-packages/graphene_django/utils/utils.py
```

Replace `<PATH_TO_utils.py>` with the path to `utils.py`

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful, but the main problem is that I cannot find the packages location in docker

Comment: @Jakubwajs Updated the answer under the assumption, that the working dir is the dir of the vent. If not, please let me know  how you create your venv

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually changing the python module in site-packages, and assuming there's no other way to fix this (i.e. if all you need is `force_text` to be defined at `django.utils.encoding`), you could also write a "monkey patch", i.e. a runtime patch of the `django.utils.encoding` module. Adding something like this in our own code (untested):

```
from django.utils import encoding

encoding.force_text = encoding.force_str
```

Later, once not needed, this patch should be removed.